# Installing latest Xamarin on Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.ios, xamarin, windows-phone

We are evaluating Xamarin Forms for our next project to develop the same application for the three major platforms: Android, iOS and Windows Phone.

As we mostly work with WP and Windows apps within the company, we have a well working base setup for work environment. It consists of a Windows 8.1 Pro/Enterprise install, Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 with both WP 8.0 and 8.1 emulators and targets, and all the rest of the packages (e.g. Office Development packages, etc.).

So I grabbed such a laptop, and installed Xamarin on it, using the official download URL on their site. It installed fine, but when I tried to create a new Forms project, it only created the Android part of it, no WP or iOS projects were created.

After checking the settings and all, it turns out that Xamarin Studio won't load the iOS and WP parts which would make it possible to create the projects.

How could I make it see those extensions?

Comment: To create iOS and WP projects, you need to use Visual Studio with the Xamarin extensions.

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 is also installed, with the Xamarin extensions. Setup basically went like this: Win8.1, Chrome, Total Commander, Visual Studio 2013 with all options, VS2013.4, Android SDK, Android NDK, GTK#, Java JDK 1.6 and 1.7, then ran the Universal Installer to finish up the missing parts.

Comment: Instead of using Xamarin Studio to create your Xamarin Project use Visual Studio to create a Xamarin forms pcl project. This should create Android, iOS and WP projects

Comment: I am doing that. Visual Studio, after setting up the iOS target, now creates the Android and iOS projects, but not the WP one (the most important one).

Comment: Creating a Shared project instead of a PCL project creates the WP project though. PCL project won't, but Shared project will. However, we need to work with a PCL project, not a Shared one.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to download the Windows phone SDK update and that will create Windows phone project for you

Comment: Which update specifically? Also, shouldn't the VS2013 installer do the update automatically?

Comment: It depends on what version of Visual studio you install if it has Windows Phone SDK. You can download the SDK from here: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/download-phone-sdk

Comment: If you have SDK installed and its not creating a Windows project, it may be because your PCL is not targeting appropriate frameworks, you might need to change the PCL settings. Have a read [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/introduction_to_portable_class_libraries/) how you can do that

Comment: Yes, I've tried changing the default PCL settings, the only issue is, I cannot find them. Editing the PCL settings after the projects have been created will not create the WinPhone project, unfortunately. A colleague of mine, who has solved a similar issue in the past, regarding PCL, can easily create a new PCL project with all three targets being created automatically, though. So there IS a way to select the default profile, but the option is hidden somewhere.